# HOWTO: Write Python API wrapper?

Tags: python, web-services, api, rest

I'd like to write a python library to wrap a REST-style API offered by a particular Web service. Does anyone know of any good learning resources for such work, preferably aimed at intermediate Python programmers?

I'd like a good article on the subject, but I'd settle for nice, clear code examples.

**CLARIFICATION:** What I'm looking to do is write a Python client to interact with a Web service -- something to construct HTTP requests and parse XML/JSON responses, all wrapped up in Python objects.

Comment: It sounds like you want to type: `app.users.john.name()` and have it go to the url `http://myapp.com/api/users/john/name`, and understand the response?

Comment: Are you interested in how to design a Python API on top of REST-style API or how to implement it?

Comment: @Richard, that would be RPC, that is not REST. You can't have resource URIs or URI patterns hard coded into a client with a REST API. It needs to discover URIs through hypertext. There should be only 1 URI that is hard coded, the entry point to the service. Otherwise you violate a constraint of REST and it is simply RPC, with all that coupling.

Comment: @RichardLevasseur you have any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

I can't point you to any article on how to do it, but I think there are a few libraries that can be good models on how to design your own.

[PyAws](http://pyaws.sourceforge.net/) for example. I didn't see the source code so I can't tell you how good it is as code example, but the features and the usage examples in their website should be a useful design model

[Universal Feed Parser](https://universal-feedparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#basic-features) is not a wrapper for a webservice (it's an RSS parser library), but it's a great example of a design that prioritizes usage flexibility and hiding implementation details. I think you can get very good usage ideas for your wrapper there.

Comment: feedparser looks nice, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite combination is httplib2 (or pycurl for performance) and simplejson. As REST is more "a way of design" then a real "protocol" there is not really a reusable thing (that I know of). On Ruby you have something like ActiveResource. And to be honest, even that would just expose some tables as a webservice, whereas the power of xml/json is that they are more like "views" that can contain multiple objects optimized for your application. I hope this makes sense :-)

Comment: Correct, there's nothing reusable, because REST is an architecture.

Comment: To be even more precise, REST is "a way to make web architectures" - aka, a meta-architecture

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial page](http://learn-rest.blogspot.com/2008/02/using-rest-in-python.html) could be a good starting place (but it doesn't contain everything you need).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at PyFacebook.  This is a python wrapper for the Facebook API, and it's one of the most nicely done API's I have ever used.

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout [pythenic jobs](http://github.com/ryanmcgrath/pythentic_jobs), a nice, simple, but well-formed "Python wrapper around the Authentic Jobs ... API" as a good example. That's what I'm doing now :)